# Is a combined subquery possible for this scenario?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, subquery

I currently have this over long query that I'm trying to optimize. I looked at combining subquery's but I fail to get a count for every group in one query while having my constraints.

Is it possible to slim down the following query?

```
SELECT
    val_year,
    spg,
    SUM(val_q1) val_q1,
    SUM(val_q2) val_q2,
    SUM(val_q3) val_q3,
    SUM(val_q4) val_q4,
    SUM(val_q1) + SUM(val_q2) + SUM(val_q3) + SUM(val_q4) val_total
FROM (
    SELECT
        val_year,
        spg,
        count_prods val_q1,
        0 val_q2,
        0 val_q3,
        0 val_q4
    FROM table_report
    WHERE val_quarter = 'Q1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        val_year,
        spg,
        0 val_q1,
        count_prods val_q2,
        0 val_q3,
        0 val_q4
    FROM table_report
    WHERE val_quarter = 'Q2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        val_year,
        spg,
        0 val_q1,
        0 val_q2,
        count_prods val_q3,
        0 val_q4
    FROM table_report
    WHERE val_quarter = 'Q3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        val_year,
        spg,
        0 val_q1,
        0 val_q2,
        0 val_q3,
        count_prods val_q4
    FROM table_report
    WHERE val_quarter = 'Q4'
)
```

table_report looks like this:

```
table_report:
val_year VARCHAR2(4)
spg VARCHAR2(256)
val_quarter VARCHAR2(2)
count_prods NUMBER(10)
```

Comment: What is the query trying to do?

Comment: creating an annual summary with quarters for every year and every spg.

Comment: Wait I had a task at the office. I thought of something I'll comment it in a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the UNIONs with a single query using CASEs:

```
SELECT
    val_year,
    spg,
    CASE WHEN val_quarter = 'Q1' THEN count_prods ELSE 0 END val_q1,
    CASE WHEN val_quarter = 'Q2' THEN count_prods ELSE 0 END val_q2,
    CASE WHEN val_quarter = 'Q3' THEN count_prods ELSE 0 END val_q3,
    CASE WHEN val_quarter = 'Q4' THEN count_prods ELSE 0 END val_q4
FROM table_report
```

Comment: Can't you can  even move the SUM/CASE to the main query?

Comment: @jarlh: you could combine everything into one query, but the `val_q?` values are used multiple times, and then you need to replicate the CASE. IMHO the code is cleaner if you keep the Derived Table.

Comment: I was thinking of something with a group by clause

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a PIVOT query, so you could do all in one

```
SELECT 
val_year, spg, 
coalesce(q1_total, 0) as q1,
coalesce(q2_total, 0) as q2,
coalesce(q3_total, 0) as q3,
coalesce(q4_total, 0) as q4,
coalesce(q1_total, 0) + coalesce(q2_total, 0) + coalesce(q3_total, 0) + coalesce(q4_total, 0) as total
FROM 
(SELECT val_Year, spg, count_prod, val_quarter FROM test) 
PIVOT (SUM(count_prod) as total
FOR (val_Quarter) IN ('Q1' AS q1, 'Q2' AS q2, 'Q3' AS q3, 'Q4' as q4))s ;
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/603cd/3)

Comment: Is the performance of PIVOT faster than using SUM(CASE ... 'Q1' ...) ?

Comment: It's probably almost the same, you can look at the execution plan. And read (old, but...) : http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2009/7/27/pivot-performance-in-11g.html

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can directly use group by query to get the sum count of each quarter -

like

select sum(count_prods) mysum, val_quarter as quarter group by quarter;

Comment: I need to select every quarter for display reasons.

Comment: for each quater, there will be row in the results. is n't help ?

Comment: I don't think what he wanted was clear. But then the answer did optimize the code. I do think that a group by clause is also possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what result you are trying to obtain, but perhaps you can try an approach like this:

```
SELECT
        val_year,
        spg,
        val_q1,
        val_q2,
        val_q3,
        val_q4,
        val_q1 + val_q2 + val_q3 + val_q4 as val_total
FROM ( 
   SELECT
        val_year,
        spg,
        sum(case when val_quarter = 'Q1' then count_prods else 0 end) as val_q1,
        sum(case when val_quarter = 'Q2' then count_prods else 0 end) as val_q2,
        sum(case when val_quarter = 'Q3' then count_prods else 0 end) as val_q3,
        sum(case when val_quarter = 'Q4' then count_prods else 0 end) as val_q4
    FROM table_report
    GROUP BY val_year, spg
)
```

Here it is in a no-data fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bf262/20